# Does <chrono> allow durations with a runtime variable ratio?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I just watched [Howard Hinnant's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M) on `<chrono>` and it seems that while you can create custom `duration`s, they require a fixed ratio at compile time. The example he gave was:

```
using frames = duration<int32_t,ratio<1,60>>;
```

which creates a `duration` called `frames` with a ratio of 1 to 60. (In other words, a video frame rate of 60 frames per second).

But what if I want to create a `duration` that has a variable ratio that can be changed at runtime?

Let's say that I want to make music software that has a user configurable beats per minute. I'd like to do something like this:

```
uint32_t nTempo {120};

using beats = duration<int32_t,ratio<1,nTempo>>;

while(running){
   // The user is turning an encoder that changes the ratio between beats and minutes.
   nTempo = ReadBPMEncoderValue();
   // Calculate the number of beats in 45 seconds plus 4 beats,
   // based on the current tempo:
   beats x = 45s + beats{4};
}
```

Is there a way to get this functionality from `<chrono>`? Do I need to write a custom extension? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Short answer: No.  Template parameters must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that `duration` and `ratio` were designed to solve is specific to compile-time concepts. Specifically, if you have a function that takes time in seconds, how do you keep people from calling it with a time in nanoseconds? Or better yet, how do you make that call automatically do the right thing?

The API would normally be just an integer, and the caller would just provide an integer. Both sides have to remember what that integer means and never get it wrong.

`duration` and `ratio` solve that problem by encoding the units of the time inside the *type itself*. If you have a function that takes a time in seconds, it takes a `duration<integer_type, seconds>`. It's right there, spelled out explicitly for everyone to see. Furthermore, a bare integer is not implicitly convertible to a `duration`; if you want to convert it, the user *must* specify a unit for that duration. This forces them to think about what this time actually means.

Lastly, `duration` can implicitly convert from one unit to another if such a conversion does not lose precision. So if an API takes nanoseconds, I can pass a seconds duration just fine.

All of these are *compile-time* issues and solutions. `ratio` is not meant for runtime conversions. So you will need to create a type to do what you're trying to do. And it wouldn't be able to do the compile-time things `ratio` does.

Comment: Is it a good practice solution to extend `<chrono>` with a runtime variable duration data type, like a `dynamic_duration` derived from `duration`? Or should a different `std` library be used? I'm thinking that a solution might be to create a `beats` `struct` that is derived from the `seconds` `duration` (and *is* a seconds duration), but has a `SetBPM()` method to change the ratio, and has overloaded operators to automatically convert any value coming out of it into a `seconds` `duration`, making it `<chrono>` compatible. 1/2

Comment: Or is any type of runtime unit conversion impossible because of the way that `<chrono>` is structured? 2/2

Comment: @Nick: You cannot add types to an existing header, nor can you add anything (other than template specializations) to the namespace `std`. And you shouldn't want to. If you have some runtime need, go write a library for that.